# confused on which flavor of linux to be installed

Tags: linux, kernel

Am doing a project in image processing and I am using **OCTAVE**. Am using a software developed by http://www.robots.ox.ac.uk/~vgg/research/affine. So i need to install Linux platform with **kernel version 2.2.0**. How should i proceed with it.

Comment: Why graphics library would require kernel features? Where can one find requirements page for the product you linked?

Comment: You very probably should try a more recent kernel version. Kernels are upward compatible. I would suggest to try on any recent Linux distribution.

Comment: I tried in ubuntu 10.10, but it is not working. I got a modglue error saying execvp process failed. So am looking for the kernel in which the software was originally developed.

Comment: `execvp` failed on which program? (use `strace` to find out). If some program is missing, install it. And this is very probably not related to a particular version of the *kernel*. Did you install the `modglue` package?

Comment: Yes sir. I installed the modglue package and I used to Strace command. I have posted a query in the following link regarding the error. "http://askubuntu.com/questions/99843/error-in-executing-a-command-in-ubuntu-modglue-error". Please visit the link.

Answer (score 1):

If you are a pro in Linux you can choose any distro and tweek it according to your needs. But if you are new to Linux try using **ubuntu or fedora**. It is easy to install and work in them (from personal experience)

Comment: Thank you sir. But i am confused on which version to be installed. Most of the Linux flavors coming now are of version 2.6.xx. I am in need of a kernel version 2.2.0.and am looking for a site to download the OS.

Comment: To install an older kernel version, you could just go to the repo website of your choice and download the rpm version you want, or if you know the exact name of the rpm, you could do >> yum install kernel#version_you_need (in Fedora)  Good luck!

Comment: [link](http://askubuntu.com/questions/80943/how-to-downgrade-kernel) to downgrade ubuntu kernel

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you find/install a distro release from 2004, you're still, in all likely-hood, not going to be able to run the program.  CV programmers are notorious for linking all kinds of outside libraries that are not going to be present on a base install of any distro.  As a fellow (ex-) CV student, I highly recommend either:

1. Contacting the authors and asking (nicely) for the source code
2. Implementing their feature detection yourself

Even with their source code, linking and compiling is still going to be a pain in the ass because, even if you find/install all of the CV/math/general dependencies, at least one of them will have deprecated *something* the code needs in the ~8 years it's been since the publication of the papers.

Your absolute best bet is to implement it yourself (perhaps, with their source as a blueprint) in Octave/MATLAB (you'll just be torturing yourself doing this in C/Java).  After all, if you can't implement it yourself, you don't really understand it :)